# How to write the following regex in Flex?

Tags: c++, regex, flex-lexer

I'm trying to define a rule in flex that will capture a "multiline string".
A multiline string is a string that starts with three apostrophes: `'''`, ends with three apostrophes, and can span over multiple lines.
For example:

```
'''This is
an example of
a multiline
string'''
```

So my attempt at this was this:

```
%{
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

%}

MULTI_LN_STR    '''(.|\n)*'''

%%

{MULTI_LN_STR}  {cout<<"GotIt!";}   

%%

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    yyin=fopen("test.txt", "r");

    if (!yyin) {
        cout<<"yyin is NULL"<<endl;
        return 1;
    }

    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

Which works for the input:

```
'''This is
a multi
line
string!'''

This is
some random
text
```

The output is:

```
GotIt!

This is
some random
text
```

but does not work (or, to be more accurate, **produces wrong output**) for this input:

```
'''This is
a multi
line
string!'''

This is
some random
text

'''and this
is another
multiline
string'''
```

Which produces:

```
GotIt!
```

This reason is because my rule says:
"scan for three apostrophes, followed by any possible character, followed by three apostrophes",
but rather, it should say:
"scan for three apostrophes, followed by any possible character **except three apostrophes**, followed by three apostrophes".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple negation like this, it is relatively easy to construct a regular expression:

```
"'''"([^']|'[^']|''[^'])*"'''"
```